# crossfade images with ability to move div container in html/css

Tags: html, css

HTML/CSS noob here. I currently have 5 images that overlay one another and fade in-and-out in 8 second intervals. In order to do this, I have set the images to have an absolute positioning.  I am now in the process of creating this site dynamically so I would like to put these crossfading images within a div ("crossfade_container") so I can then center them as the browser size changes. Obviously, with the absolute positioning on the images itself will not allow for this dynamic positioning.

The following is my HTML:

```
<div class="crossfade_container">
  <div id="crossfade">
      <img src="Images/Michigan_1.png" />
      <img src="Images/Miller_1.png" />
      <img src="Images/OSU_Helmets.png" />
      <img src="Images/Go_Blue.png" />
      <img src="Images/OSU_UM.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is my CSS to create crossfade between images:

```
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 441px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s; 
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
    -o-animation-delay: 32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
    animation-delay: 32s; 
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    5% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }
```

To this point, everything is how I would like it. It's the dynamic aspect of the code that is confusing me. Here is the following code I am using to no avail:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width: 695px) {

.crossfade_container {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        background-color: red;
        width: 480px;
        height: 255px;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
  #crossfade > img {
    width: 480px;
    height: 235px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

With this, ".crossfade_container" is exactly where I want it and by changing the position to "relative" within "#crossfade > img" only the first image in the series appears where I would like it. Now instead of the images being stacked on top of one another, they now appear in series going down the page - as if they are block elements (hope that makes sense).

Please help & let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks.

Comment: you could use `position: relative;` to `.crossfade_container` and `position: absolute;` to `#crossfade > img` and it will work dynamically like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/q3ukoo48/3/ and for more info about position check that Mozilla MDN doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: that seemed to do the trick! thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using css `position: relative;` to `.crossfade_container` and `position: absolute;` to `#crossfade > img`

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q3ukoo48/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="crossfade_container">
    <div id="crossfade">
        <img src="Images/Michigan_1.png" style="background: red;">
        <img src="Images/Miller_1.png" style="background: blue;">
        <img src="Images/OSU_Helmets.png" style="background: pink;">
        <img src="Images/Go_Blue.png" style="background: orange;">
        <img src="Images/OSU_UM.png" style="background: black;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#crossfade > img {
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
    -o-animation-delay: 32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
    animation-delay: 32s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    5% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width: 695px) {
    .crossfade_container {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        background-color: red;
        width: 480px;
        height: 255px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #crossfade > img {
        width: 480px;
        height: 235px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        color: transparent;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

**For More Info:**

> [Mozilla MDN CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)